# The value '(SomeNumber)' is not valid for Number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, dto

i'm using data annotation and it's a simple project about phone book I want to add a person  ,I don't know why I am receiving

> The value '09124573957' is not valid for Number

error under my editor box while I press the button Create

here is my dto in view model

```
   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_Globaliz.Resource1), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Number")]
    [DisplayName("Number")]
  //  [Phone]
    [Range (0, 09889999999, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Range", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_Globaliz.Resource1))]
    public int Num { get; set; }
```

you should know that i'm using a resource file which I wrote some errors text in it but this error I don't know where did it came from

Comment: Because of the leading `0`, and if that was removed, it would be outside the range for `int` anyway. Your property needs to be `string`

Comment: May be reason that `int.MaxValue` is less than 9889999999? Try to change `int`  to the `long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `range validator` is not working because numeric do not support leading zero .. and `range validator works on numeric type`

It will be working using `RegularExpression validator`... something like this ...

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_Globaliz.Resource1), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Number")]
[Display(Name = "Number")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid number")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: Good answer, and I was also going to suggest (but you've already used it) the `DataType.PhoneNumber`. Also, with the range validation - even if you removed the trailing zero, the number would still be larger than `int.MaxValue` (as @StephenMuecke has already pointed out) :)

Answer (score 2):

Number data types (int, double, etc.) are for doing Math! Just ask yourself: could it be useful to add two of those numbers, e.g. what's the meaning of the sum of your telephone number and your friend's? If that does not make sense at all, it is not a number.

Telephone numbers are strings, though they are commonly called numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Phone Numbers should be stored as strings rather than numbers

Because:

1. Some numbers start with 0 or + which cannot be stored in any numeric value (e.g. "002121132434" or "+9772323212"
2. You will need to search for phone numbers as string (e.g. numbers starting with specific substrings represent specific regions or specific service providers)
3. You will need to do some string formatting (e.g. "+977-232-3212")
4. You will never need to do mathematical operation (e.g. you will never add or subtract 2 phone numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Integers do not support leading zeros. You should not see this error if you try to set the value `9124573957`. **EDIT**: this will only work if you use `long` instead of `int` to store the value, because 9124573957 is bigger than `int.MaxValue`.

If you have to support leading zeros, you have to store the value as `string`.

Comment: Max value for `int` is `2147483647` so it would still cause an error :)

Comment: same happened even for 9124573957

Comment: @NeverTrust you have to change your type to `long` instead of `int` if you want numbers instead of `string`s

Comment: What reference do you have regarding "Integers do not support leading zeros"?

Comment: I can't find a reference, but you can try for yourself: `var number1 = long.Parse("9124573957");
  var number2 = long.Parse("09124573957");
  Console.WriteLine(number1 == number2);`